# View Record Lock Details in DB2 for z/OS

Tags: db2, db2-zos

An overnight job encountered a locking error on updating a record in DB2 10 for z/OS. I've been asked to inspect the DB2 logs to hopefully find more information on what was locking the table. Since I have the timestamp of the failure, how can I look at the DB2 log for a specific time-period?

Thanks for your help!

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in `SDSF DA`, there should be an entry for `*MSTR` (e.g., if your DB2 subsystem name is `DB2P` for your production DB2, then you'd look at `DB2PMSTR`). If you look at the `JESMSGLG` of that task, the DB2 logs you are interested will be in there. There should be a [`DSNT375I`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/msgs/src/tpc/dsnt375i.html) (deadlock) or  [`DSNT376I`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/msgs/src/tpc/dsnt376i.html) (timeout) entry that will look something like the below (the format is slightly different between the two).

The two error messages will also have a [`DSNT501I`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/msgs/src/tpc/dsnt501i.html) error associated with it that will tell you what the "fight" was over.

```
12.48.05 STC30099  DSNT376I  -DB2P PLAN=DISTSERV WITH  798                      
   798                     CORRELATION-ID=program.exe                              
   798                     CONNECTION-ID=SERVER                                 
   798                     LUW-ID=GA5D2A01.CE00.200429174636=79816              
   798                                                                          
   798             THREAD-INFO=logon_username:server_name:logon_username:program.exe:DYNAMIC:7522055:*:<10
   798             .93.42.1.52736.200429174636>                                 
   798                     IS TIMED OUT. ONE HOLDER OF THE RESOURCE IS PLAN=plan WITH
   798                     CORRELATION-ID=ENTRabcdefgh                          
   798                     CONNECTION-ID=CICSzyxw                               
   798                     LUW-ID=USDTCN00.ALDB2P00.D7D81AEAB200=43579          
   798                     THREAD-INFO=CICSzyxw:*:*:ENTRabcd:STATIC:9507687:*:* 
   798                     ON MEMBER DB2P                                       
12.48.05 STC30099  DSNT501I  -DB2P DSNILMCL RESOURCE UNAVAILABLE  799           
   799                        CORRELATION-ID=program.exe                           
   799                        CONNECTION-ID=SERVER                              
   799                        LUW-ID=GA5D2A01.CE00.200429174636=79816           
   799                        REASON 00C9008E                                   
   799                        TYPE 00000304                                     
   799                        NAME DBNAME .TBSPACE  .X'abcdefg12'.X'11'
```

In my example, `program.exe` (logged on as user `logon_username` from client `server_name`) was trying to access a page (Identified by `X'abcdefg12'.X'11'`) in database `DBNAME`, tablespace `TBSPACE` (the format is determined by the [resource type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/msgs/src/tpc/db2z_resourcetypes.html) listed in the 501 error code). The page was being held by a CICS task, identified by `ENTRabcdefgh` in region `CICSzyxw`.

Hopefully that gets you the information you're looking for.

Comment: you nailed it! Thanks!